If $3$ or $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $T,$ then $9$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2$
Here is the question I am trying to solve using only theorems (without using the procedure of finding the eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors) of "linear algebra done right", fourth edition, chapter 5.
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V).$ Prove that $9$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2$ if and only if $3$ or $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
My thoughts:
$\Leftarrow$
Let $3$ or $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ I want to prove that $9$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2.$ Assume that $Tv = 3v$ for some vector $v$ and $Tw = 3w$ for some vector $w.$ but then I do not know how to complete. I want to prove that $T^2 v = 9v$.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
$\Rightarrow$
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V).$ Assume that $9$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2$ and I want to prove that $3$ or $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
Well, we know that $T^2 v = 9v$ for some vector $v.$ then $((T - 3)(T + 3)) v = 0$ then $T = 3 $ or $T = -3$.
Am I correct?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried applying $T$ iteratively for the first part?

For the second direction, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3441465/42969

You need to specify a non-zero vector $v$.

$((T-3I)(T+3I))v=0$ for some $v$ does not imply $T-3I=0$ or $T+3I=0$.

It is not exactly well written. I would say that if $T^2$ has eigenvalue $9$, then $(T-3I)(T+3I)v=0$. If $(T+3I)v$ is zero, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ of eigenvalue $-3$, otherwise, if $(T+3I)v$ is different from zero, then  $(T+3I)v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ of eigenvalue $3$.
Thus, $T$ has eigenvalues $3$ or $-3$.
Regarding the other direction, if $T$ has eigenvalues $3$ or $-3$, then let us consider a correspondent eigenvector $v\neq 0$. Then
$$ T^2v=T(Tv)=T(3v)=3Tv=9v \qquad  \text{or} \qquad T^2v=T(Tv)=T(-3v)=(-3)Tv=(-3)^2v=9v$$
so that $v$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $9$ for $T^2$.

what about the other direction proof, it is my main question actually.

I answered also the other direction :)

Well, but I have a question with this answer. In particular, just because $ABv = 0$, does not imply $Av=0$ or $Bv=0$, even assuming $A$ and $B$ commute. An example is the $2 \times 2$ matrix $J$ where the upper-right entry is $1$ and the remaining $3$ entries are $0$. Then  $J^2(1,1)^{\top} = 0$ but $J(1,1)^{\top}$ is nonzero.

The answer posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441465/lambda2-is-an-eigenvalue-of-a2-prove-that-lambda-or-lambda-is-an observes only that one of $A+3I, $A-3I$ is not invertible, which gives you the rest i.e., some $v$ such that $Av=0$ we don't know which yet. Yes $(A \pm 3I)v = \pm 3v$ readily gives $A^2v= 9v$ that is straightforward. But I am not seeing the other direction $A^2v = 9v \implies Av = \pm 3v$.

The answer from the links in comments observes only that one of $A+3I, $A-3I$ is not invertible, which gives you the rest i.e., some $v$ such that $(A \pm 3I)v=0$ [depending on which of $A+3I$, $A-3I$, or both, is non-invertible, we don't know which $v$ yet and  the previous answer is not claiming that every $v$ that satisfies $A^2v =9v$ will satisfy either $Av = \pm 3v$. Yes every $v$ satisfying $Av = \pm 3v$ satisfies $A^2v= 9v$ that is straightforward. But I am not seeing the other direction $A^2v = 9v \implies Av = \pm 3v$.

I don't understand. I never said that $Av$ is zero or $Bv$ is zero. I only found either a non zero vector belonging to the kernel of $A=T-3I$ or, if it is zero, then I found a non zero vector belonging to the kernel of $B=T+3I$.

Regarding “the other direction”. Would be a correct proof to say that if -3 or 3 is eigenvalue, then for some non zero $v$ we have $((T + 3I)(T- 3I))v =0 and then T^2v - 9v = 0, and therefore 9 is eigenvalue?
